# Flutter button onPressed() not firing within GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, button, gesturedetector

Sorry I'm quite new to flutter, I'm trying to adapt this code example https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter_vignettes/tree/master/vignettes/gooey_edge.

There's a Card widget containing a MaterialButton, this is wrapped within a GestureDetector. When you try to click/tap on the MaterialButton for the first time, the onTap() in the GestureDetector is triggered (not the button), the second tap is recognised by the MaterialButton. Is there some way to force the priority of the button tap?
I thought a work around might also be to determine the location of the button and trigger the same action in the onTap(), this is not ideal as the ripple effect wouldn't occur.

Edit: To give a bit more information, the GestureDetector is needed for the animation effect used when swiping to the next card.
The GestureDetector code is here https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter_vignettes/blob/master/vignettes/gooey_edge/lib/gooey_carousel.dart

The card with the button is - https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter_vignettes/blob/master/vignettes/gooey_edge/lib/content_card.dart

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: What is the goal / reason for having a Button wrapped in a gesture detector? Do you need to only have one or the other trigger in a certain order? Some more background would be good